# PowerShell out-file formats

Tags: powershell

I'm wanting to output the contents on my txt file in the below format.

```
"Web-ISAPI-Filter", "Web-Mgmt-Tools"
```

I'm using the below script but would like some help to modify the output formats if any.

```
Get-Service | Out-File process.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
(Get-Service | %{ '"{0}"' -f $_.Name }) -join ',' | Out-File 'process.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say for a good balance between concision and readability [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899077/45375) is the way to go, but here's a shorter alternative:

```
"`"$((Get-Service).Name -join '", "')`"" > process.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think to do this is with a custom function to parse the string into a single line.  you can probably simplify this and do it as a one-liner if you want but imo this is easier to read.

```
function Build-String{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param(
    [parameter(valuefrompipeline=$true)]$string
  )
  Begin{
    $result = ""
  }
  Process{
    foreach($s in $string){
        $result += "$($s),"
    }
  }
  end{
    return $result.TrimEnd(",")
  }
}

Get-Service | select -ExpandProperty Name | Build-String | Out-File 'process.txt'
```